# DNN custom skin made login page disappear

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I am new to DNN and I'm trying to make a site with custom skin.
Skinning is all ok but once the superuser is time out, I couldn't login again.

The login page has disappeared and was being redirected to an empty custom skin page which only shows the header and the footer.

I have tried

- localhost:1234/login
- localhost:1234/admin
- localhost:1234/?ctl=

but neither of them are working.

I tried to search for solutions but none of them seems to work and not relating.
Please show me a way, if I am missing somethings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at the Admin/Event Viewer page if you happen to still be logged in somehow (or eventlog table in the database) to see if there is an error being thrown, that isn't being displayed (because you aren't logged in).

That may point to the problem.

You might have a problem with a "container" that is missing thus the module isn't being loaded.

A few other things to try, try

localhost:1234/?ctl=login
localhost:1234/?ctl=register

See if anything loads for those.

Last resort, go into the database and NULL out the SKinSRC columns on the TABS table and see if you can find the default site Skin setting in the PortalSettings and make that null or something other than your custom skin.

Comment: Hi, thanks i got it now. anyway, I got another problem.. it's not related with this issue tho. The problem is i couldn't get an ajax called function in my custom module, any solution to deal with this problem? I posted the issue here too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178142/dotnetnuke-call-ajax-from-a-module